# Code Igniter - Form Validation (No Error Messages)

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I'm having real trouble with Code Igniter. I have tried to enable errors which displays nothing useful and as far as I am aware, I am following the docs correctly. The problem I am having is that the validation_errors() function in the template does not echo validation problems. The validation process is working (it returns to the form if validation fails) however no error message is shown. Also, the set_values() function does not populate the fields with the information just entered and populates with the default value instead.

The tpl file is very basic and have the correct functions etc so that is not included (large),   I have however included the method from the controller below.

```
    // Setup Error Specifics

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="nNote nFailure hideit"><p><strong>FAILURE: </strong>', '</p></div>');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company_name', 'Company Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('telephone_no', 'Telephone Number', 'required|is_natural');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'required|valid_email');

    // Begin Validation

    if($this->form_validation->run() === false) {

        $data = array();
        $data['company_info'] = $this->company_model->get_company($this->input->get('company_id'));

        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('company/edit', $data);
        $this->load->view('common/footer');

    } else {

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_message', 'You have updated the company record(s)');
        redirect('customer/company/listing', 'location');

    }
```

I appreciate your help,
Thanks!

UPDATE ---

After digging around the core of CodeIgniter, I've narrowed my search for the problem down to some hooks I am using. I have fully commented out the method code for each of the two hooks (both are post_controller_constructor hooks). Even with the code of each hook commented out, the form validation still fails. It appears (unless I'm heading down the wrong path) that post_controller_constructor hooks cause problems with form validation.

Any Ideas??

Comment: UPDATE: I have already autoloaded the required helpers / libraries etc.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code from the view?

Comment: Straight from the top of the view:

<div class="title"><h5>Company Editor</h5></div>

<div class="pt20">
 <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
</div>

Comment: Are you calling the same method in the form action, right? Code looks ok...Unrelated sidenote: using is_natural() as a phone number validation could be a bit frustrating for the user (if you're not being helped by some js mask)

Comment: Same method, to be honest, first time using the form validation functionality of Code Igniter so just playing with it at the moment, rules are not final. Any ideas where to go then? I can't see a problem...

Comment: Just updated the question with new findings :)

Comment: Ok fixed!!

The reason was unrelated to the code I was running and displaying on this question, it was related to how I had implemented the hooks in CodeIgniter. I had extended the core CI controller for the hook (which was the wrong thing to do). I have now modified the hook to use the get_instance() method of retrieving the CI instance and have managed to obviously achieve the same functionality from the hook without causing this issue.

So my fault!

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @Joe: Please feel free to post your solution as an answer below, for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed!!

The reason was unrelated to the code I was running and displaying on this question, it was related to how I had implemented the hooks in CodeIgniter. I had extended the core CI controller for the hook (which was the wrong thing to do). I have now modified the hook to use the get_instance() method of retrieving the CI instance and have managed to obviously achieve the same functionality from the hook without causing this issue.

So my fault!

Thanks for your help anyway!